# Run SQL statements that are saved in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table dbo.usp_table with the following records:

```
    EXEC USP_one
    EXEC USP_two
    EXEC USP_three
```

I want to execute these 3 or more stored procedures.
I could do this with a cursor.

However is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: No really.  A cursor is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + YourColumn + '; '
FROM YourTable;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Where the column `YourColumn` contains the SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable and store all the values(exec procedurename) inside the table into that variable appended with space at the end and execute the variable. Try this

```
declare @exec_proc nvarchar(max)=''
select @exec_proc += proc_name+' ' from dbo.usp_table
-- print @exec_proc
exec sp_executesql @exec_proc
```

Note : This will not work if your procedure accepts parameters